# How to specify "start" document in the elasticsearch SearchQuery using java? (skip number of documents)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a SearchQuery I've constructed like this:

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .withQuery(queryString("A"))                .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("fruitId").order(SortOrder.DESC))                
            .withIndices("fruit").withTypes("fruit");
```

I want to be able to specify some sort of "start" and "size" on the search results so that I can:

1) Return the number of results based on the "size".

2) Return documents with based on the "Start" integer. For example, if my documents where A,B,C,D,E...Z If my "start" was set to 5 and "size" was set to 5, it would return "F,G,H,I,J".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Spring Data Elasticsearch, you need to call the [`withPageable()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/NativeSearchQueryBuilder.html#withPageable-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withPageable(new PageRequest(1, 5))        <--- add this
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withQuery(queryString("A"))                
    .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("fruitId").order(SortOrder.DESC))                
    .withIndices("fruit").withTypes("fruit");
```

The `PageRequest` constructor takes two arguments: `page` (0-based) and `size`. Here we're asking for the second page (i.e. page 1) of size 5. This is going to return you exactly what you need.

Official documentation of the [`PageRequest` class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html).

Note, however, that your query still has a problem, i.e. you're calling `withQuery()` twice, so the second call will override the first one. In this case, it might be ok since the first call is a `matchAll` (basically, return everything) and the second call is more specific. But if you want to combine two different queries, you'll need to proceed differently and use a `boolQuery` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need [From/Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html):

```
{
    "from" : 5, "size" : 5,
    "query": {
     ....
     }
}
```

Comment: If I could just pass this exact string into a query using Java, it would be so easy!